# Basic SQL user trying to understand advanced SUM functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I'm going through the "Select within Select" tutorial on SQLzoo.net. It occurred to me that I'd like to know the total area of each continent. The table `world` has 5 columns.

1. `name` is country name
2. `continent` is for where the country belongs
3. `area` is for the total area of each country
4. `population` is present but not needed for this
5. `gdp` is present but not needed for this

I want my result to be two columns(`Continent` and `Area`). I want Area to be the sum of each country's `area` located on the same `Continent`.

How can I separate out the countries by `continent` and then add them to the appropriate `continent` in the data returned?

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(area),continent
from world
group by continent
```

The grouping create groups of records based on the group by field, then the sum function sums up the total of the group.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the GROUP BY operator in addition to SUM:

```
SELECT continent, SUM(area) as total_area
FROM table
GROUP BY continent
```

Group by allows you to do aggregation operations on columns.

Comment: thanks!  i was WAY overthinking this.  i had sub select clauses going and...well, not anywhere near how simple this was.